# How can I check if a user exist on a sql db, with a ms entity CRUD api controller, with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, entity-framework-core

I'm using Visual Studio, .net 5, swagger and Entity Framework Core.

I'm trying to check if a user has created a profile in SQL Server. I use MS Graph API to get the "UserID" of the user. Now I want to check if this person has used this app before, so I send this "UserID" to my Entity Framework API controller.

At the API I have use the "code 1" (look below), which does a SQL query. I want to send back to my app that it does not exist. I have tried different things. I'm not asking about the SQL query. I'm asking about the API. It refuses to let me return a false or anything.

How can I change code snippet #1 to let me send a false back to the mobile app?

Code snippet #1

```
[HttpGet("GetUserexist/{userms}")]
// GET: api/Users/GetUseridms/
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUserexist(string userms)
{
    string StoredProc = "exec CheckIfUserExist " + "@UserID_MS = '" + userms + "'";

    return await _context.Users.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Code snippet #2 (stored procedure)

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [User]
                    WHERE UserId_MS = @UserId_MS)
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
   END
```

Comment: You are using an HTTP Request and get back an HTTP Response which normal status of 200 OK or a 400/500 error.  The API client sends the HTTP Request/Response to a server and the server add the status to the response.  When a credential fails the server should return a 400/500 error.  You have no control over the request/response which is done with the API and Server software.  All you can do is check if a 200 OK is returned or if an 400/500 error occurs. So if you are getting a 200 OK than there is nothing you can do.  The server already determine the credentials are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I managed to do myself, if anyone else needs this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsersMS(string userms)
        {

            string StoredProc = "exec FindUserIDAndUserID_MS " +
                    "@UserID_MS = '" + userms + "'";

            var user = await _context.Users.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToListAsync();
            if (user.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(user);

        }
```